# how to use supersu in cm12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

Cyanogenmod has a built-in root access control in developer options. 
But I can't use supersu instead of it. 
If i install supersu and update the su binary. Then after reboot phone becomes unstable and many apps crashes. 
If I flash update-supersu.zip from recovery the app gets installed in
 /system and built-in root access doesn't work and I can't remove supersu app, then I don't have any option but to reinstall Rom. 
How to get it working? 
Tnx for any help.

Comment: You can remove SuperSU app easily. SuperSU (by Chainfire) has the option for cleanup. Besides, if you've root access, you can remove pretty much anything, so why do you say you've to reinstall ROM?

Comment: I have root access available but when I try to switch from inbuilt access control to SuperSU by flashing from recovery I don't have root access and SuperSU won't even open. And I can't do anything because phone hangs a lot.

Comment: Are you using a stable CM build?

Comment: It's unofficial but very stable, 
Only crashes in this case